Is a connected, smooth codimension one submanifold of R^n with an everywhere upward pointing normal a graph globally?
Let $S \subset R^{n-1} \times R \cong R^n$ be a connected, codimension one submanifold and denote, for each $q \in S$, the normal to $T_q S$ by $(v_1(q),\ldots,v_n(q))$. Suppose now $v_n(q) > 0 \; \forall q \in S$.
Question: Does it then follow there exists a smooth function $f : R^{n-1} \rightarrow R$ such that $S = \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})),\; (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) \in R^{n-1} \}$?
To approach this I naturally looked at the "Global Characterization of Graphs" result in Lee's ISM, which is Theorem 6.32 (I know there are other versions of this but Theorem 6.32 is the one I am most familiar with). My sense is that the upward pointing normal will imply, somehow, that for each $p \in R^{n-1}$, the manifolds $S$ and $\{p\} \times R$ will intersect exactly once (I'm forgetting about transversality for the moment).
Not seeing this immediately I tried specializing to the very simple case of $n = 2$. In this case the two dimensional normal vector to $S$ has everywhere a strictly positive second coordinate, which means that the tangent vector $T_q S$ at each point of $S$  cannot have a zero first coordinate. That is, as we travel around $S$ the tangent vector has everywhere either a strictly positive or strictly negative first coordinate. If $S$ is connected then it is path connected; thus, if there existed two real numbers $r, r^\prime$ such that both $(p,r)$ and $(p,r^\prime)$ were in $S$, then there would exist a smooth curve $C$ connecting the two (I know it's only piecewise smooth but it can be made smooth everywhere), which would be impossible since the first coordinate of the tangent vector at each point of $C$ has the same sign, which means that $p$ is either always increasing or always decreasing.
Second Question: Is my approach in the $n=2$ case correct?
Third Question: In the general case is the answer to the Title yes?
Any light you can shed on this situation, or any suggestions you can make as to how to answer the question myself, would be appreciated.
Update: Moishe Kohan and Jack Lee have kindly pointed out, while this is true for $n=2$ (in which case I guess my partial proof is more or less OK), it is not true for $n \geq 3$. Jack Lee referred me to the helicoid for a counter-example in three dimensions. This, however, brings up an additional question (for which I can create a new post, if necessary): Would my conjecture be true if the normal to the manifold were required to be always non-negative, with an always positive last coordinate? I noticed the normal to the helicoid does not satisfy this requirement (the first two coordinates can be of opposite sign).

This is simply false if $n\ge 3$.

Thank you, that at least tells me my utter inability to get anywhere in higher dimensions was to be expected.

For a counterexample in dimension 3, consider the helicoid with the $z$-axis removed.

OK, I appreciate you taking the time to point that out.

I was looking at the helicoid that Jack Lee referenced. I know I might need to create a new question, which I will if necessary, but would changing the condition to requiring that all the coordinates of the normal be non-negative, with say the last one always strictly positive, change things? If either of you (or anyone) could give me a pointer or a hint to approaching this question I'd appreciate it.
